# data manipulation in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data like below:

```
   col1      col2         
   A         0              
   A         1             
   B         0              
   A         0              
   C         1               
   B         1               
   C         0
```

I like it as below:

```
  col1      col2    col3      col4
   A         0       .33       .33 
   A         1       .33       .33
   B         0       .5        .33
   A         0       .33       .33
   C         1       .5        .33
   B         1       .5        .33
   C         0       .5        .33
```

Col 1 are categories of values. Col 2 are events,i.e 0=no, 1=yes.
col 3 should be the event rate of the category,i.e 
(number of times the category has value 1/total number of occurances of that category)
col 4 should be event share of the category,i.e, 
(number of times the category has value1/total number of 1s across all categories,
e.g col 4 for A should be number of 1s in A divided by number of total 1s across categories A,B & C together.)

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `mean` and `sum`, for second divide by sum of all `1` of `df['col2']`:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('mean')
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('sum').div(df['col2'].sum())
print (df)
  col1  col2      col3      col4
0    A     0  0.333333  0.333333
1    A     1  0.333333  0.333333
2    B     0  0.500000  0.333333
3    A     0  0.333333  0.333333
4    C     1  0.500000  0.333333
5    B     1  0.500000  0.333333
6    C     0  0.500000  0.333333
```

Another solution with aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.join(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg([('col3','mean'),('col4','sum')])
               .assign(col4 = lambda x: x['col4'].div(df['col2'].sum())), on='col1')
print (df)
  col1  col2      col3      col4
0    A     0  0.333333  0.333333
1    A     1  0.333333  0.333333
2    B     0  0.500000  0.333333
3    A     0  0.333333  0.333333
4    C     1  0.500000  0.333333
5    B     1  0.500000  0.333333
6    C     0  0.500000  0.333333
```